# Is the chalk really needed in the "chalk and string labyrinth" analogy for depth-first search?

Tags: depth-first-search

I came across the chalk-and-string labyrinth analogy for depth-first search in *Algorithms* by Dasgupta et al.  I have seen the code for the depth first search.

> Everybody knows that all you need to explore a labyrinth is a ball of string and a piece of chalk. The chalk prevents looping, by marking the junctions you have already visited. The string always takes you back to the starting place, enabling you to return to passages that you previously saw but did not yet investigate.

How a computer does it in code makes sense, but as a human, I think that the string is sufficient. why would I need the chalk, wouldn't see the string indicate that I have already passed a junction?

Comment: You don’t see the string, because the computer doesn’t store past values of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all keep in mind that this is just an analogy meant to convey the intuition behind the DFS algorithm on graphs.

Now graphs can be directed, which would correspond to having a labyrinth with junctions/rooms and one-way pathways between them.
Then it is possible for you to be in some room $r_0$ and to travel to some other room $r_1 \neq r_0$ as a part of your labyrinth exploration.
Maybe all paths from $r_1$ lead to a dead end, so you backtrack to $r_0$. From there you continue to explore until you reach a third room $r_2 \not\in \{r_0, r_1\}$.
The problem arises if $r_2$ has a pathway to $r_1$: without any record that you already visited $r_1$, you'd visit it again.

To stick with your analogy, you don't need strings if the floor plan of your labyrinth can be represented as a tree (rather than a general graph). Indeed, if you have a tree and some (arbitrary) order among the edges from a vertex to their children (as it is usually the case in actual implementations), you can implement a DFS without keeping any information other than the current and previous vertices of the search (i.e., an edge of the tree).

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning that there may be a path from $r_2$ to $r_1$ after having backtracked (wound back my string).

Comment: Could you clarify the tree part - especially just needing the previous and current vertices? They way I see it is that if we pick in a particular (not arbitrary order) edges from left to right (looking at all the routes when I arrive from the junction), then when I backtrack I would say that everything to my right (now facing in the opposite direction) is done. If I pick any other order, I would need to have a way to "remember" and so the chalk would be needed here.

Comment: Since you already decided on an (arbitrary but fixed) order of the outgoing edges from each vertex, when you're travelling backwards from a vertex $u$  to $v$ you know that all the edges that come not after $(v,u)$ in you order have already been traversed, while all edges after $(v,u)$ have not yet been traverses (and their corresponding subtrees have not been visited). The left-to-right order is just an easy-to-visualize order.

Comment: In practice the edges are going to be stored somewhere (e.g., in a list/array for each node, in a matrix,...) so your order can just be the natural order induced by the used collection. Other choices are possible, e.g., if the edges from $v$ to its children are $e_1,e_2,\dots$ (as they appear in the collection), then you could traverse all the even-indexed edges first, in increasing order of index, followed by all odd-indexed edges, in decreasing order. You're still able to tell which edge needs to be traversed next. Of course this is an overly-complicated order that only serves as an example.